# Having trouble with Console.Writeline

Tags: vb.net

Can someone explain why the below code won't work? It's supposed to find the average in a group of 15 numbers, then assign a letter grade to them. From what I can tell, the problem is in the If statement, although I can't seem to find what it is that causes the problem.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim Input1 As Integer
        Dim Input2 As Integer
        Dim Input3 As Integer
        Dim Input4 As Integer
        Dim Input5 As Integer

        Dim Input6 As Integer
        Dim Input7 As Integer
        Dim Input8 As Integer
        Dim Input9 As Integer
        Dim Input10 As Integer

        Dim Input11 As Integer
        Dim Input12 As Integer
        Dim Input13 As Integer
        Dim Input14 As Integer
        Dim Input15 As Integer

        Dim Adder As Integer
        Dim Divider As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 1/15")
        Input1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 2/15")
        Input2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 3/15")
        Input3 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 4/15")
        Input4 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 5/15")
        Input5 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 6/15")
        Input6 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 7/15")
        Input7 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 8/15")
        Input8 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 9/15")
        Input9 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 10/15")
        Input10 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 11/15")
        Input11 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 12/15")
        Input12 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 13/15")
        Input13 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 14/15")
        Input14 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number 15/15")
        Input15 = Console.ReadLine()

        Adder = (Input1) + (Input2) + (Input3) + (Input4) + (Input5) + (Input6) + (Input7) + (Input8) + (Input9) + (Input10) + (Input11) + (Input12) + (Input13) + (Input14) + (Input15)
        Divider = Adder / 15

        If 100 >= Divider >= 90 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is an A, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf 89 >= Divider >= 80 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a B, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf 79 >= Divider >= 70 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a C, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf 69 >= Divider >= 60 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a D, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf 59 >= Divider Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is an F, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What error did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the following:

```
If 100 >= Divider >= 90
```

I believe that is interpreted to be something like

```
If (100 >= Divider) >= 90
```

Where it is comparing a boolean converted to a integer.

To get a check for that range you would need to do:

```
If (100 >= Divider) AndAlso (Divider >= 90)
```

In short you have bad syntax with your If Check

As an added note, I would reccomend taking advantage of the strength of conditional logic by skipping the range checks and doing something like:

```
    If Divider >= 90 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is an A, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
    ElseIf Divider >= 80 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a B, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
    ElseIf Divider >= 70 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a C, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
    ElseIf Divider >= 60 Then
        Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a D, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is an F, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
    End If
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you feel like my response was the correct one, please mark the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You made an error in reasoning.

The `Divider` in your case has a Maximum value of 15. so it's obviously always an F Grade.

```
        If Adder >= 90 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is an A, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf Adder >= 80 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a B, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf Adder >= 70 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a C, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf Adder >= 60 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is a D, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        ElseIf Adder < 60 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your average Grade is an F, and your average in numbers is {0}", Divider)
        End If
```

Here you go. I just switched the `Divider` with `Adder` and erased some non-essentiel stuff.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: From my understanding his number is not restricted to be between 1-15, it is just a set of 15 numbers, say nr. 1 is 90 and nr. 2 is 5 and so on.

Comment: @SimonJensen That's why I wrote "Hope this i what you are looking for". As my mind reading skills are not perfect yet I have to deal with what is given. 
If this is not the solution he was looking for, I'd be glad to help him further on :)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, sorry if I seemed rude, just tried to clear up some confusion.

Comment: I have to apologize too. Your interpretation makes actually way more sense. But if there is no given range for the 15 numbers, the grade matrix makes no sense at all in my opinion

Comment: The real fix in your answer is that you corrected the syntax of the If statements. Divider should be the correct value to use.